# How do I re-add a branched build that Bamboo has automatically deleted?

Tags: build, branch, bamboo

I've got a branched build in Bamboo which is configured to delete builds after 14 days.

Usually branches aren't inactive that long in our project, however with Christmas leave and some early New Year priorities one branch has been inactive for more than 14 days. As a result it has dropped out of the branched build list.

How do I add it back in Bamboo?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at this post:
[Deleted plans are not remade when code is pushed to existing branch.](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-12161?focusedCommentId=642486&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-642486)

> 1. Go to Plan Configuration -> Branches, and click button in upper-right to manually add a branch.
> 2. From branch add modal, select desired branch and check box for 'Enable branches'.
> 3. (optional) on following screen for new plan branch, check the box to exempt this branch from getting pruned again.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. I've also voted for https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-12161 which you linked to.